# Looping throug cells and move to diffrent sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to look throug the first cell in each row to see if it meets a string criteria and if it does copy and paste that line in to another sheet in the same workbook.

The problem im facing is that the code does not loop throug each line.
If i test with 80 lines, im left with 40 lines that has noe been copied.
Im then able to run the script again and it leaves me with 20 lines and then so on until all lines are gone.

Appreciate any help as this is the first Excel macro im coding

```
Public Sub moveRow()

 Sheets("Ark1").Select
     ' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     ' Loop through each row


For Each loopRow In Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows:

    ' Decide if to copy based on column D
   ThisValue = Cells(1, 1).Value
    If ThisValue = "a" Or ThisValue = "g" Then
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        Sheets("a").Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Ark1").Select
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 33).Delete
        
    ElseIf ThisValue = "Vy" Or ThisValue = "b" Then
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        Sheets("b").Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Ark1").Select
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 33).Delete
        
        
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are `Sheets("Ark1")` and `Sheets(1)` the same worksheet? You are not using `FinalRow` anywhere else.

Comment: I voted reopen because 'proper' codes would show how the conflicts between backing up data to multiple sheets by checking rows 'ascending' and the need to delete the rows 'descending' can be solved. Only the latter (deleting rows) is covered in the associated 'closing' post.

Comment: @julian to address the order of copy, see the Union method in the second linked duplicate